# How do I use TemplateHTMLRenderer for Create/Put in Django-REST-Framework?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm having a terrible time finding the right way to initialize the **TemplateHTMLRenderer** to render a form for creating an object.  My API works perfectly for post (the DRF browsable API form) but that's not a frontend solution.

I can create a detail page using the docs and template packs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms.  The docs are very clear on how to create an UPDATE form.

But I can't for the life of me initialize the same form to do the initial create.

I don't want to have to manually write forms to interact with the API for creating objects when the feature for auto-generated forms is there... but I'm completely at a loss.

From views.py the working update view:

```
class LicensedSoftwareDetail(APIView):
    model = LicensedSoftware
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'licsoftware-detail.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        if pk:
            licensedsoftware = get_object_or_404(LicensedSoftware, pk=pk)
            serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(licensedsoftware)
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'licensedsoftware': licensedsoftware})
        else:
            serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer()
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if pk:
            licensedsoftware = get_object_or_404(LicensedSoftware, pk=pk)
            serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(licensedsoftware, data=request.data)
            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'licensedsoftware': licensedsoftware})
            serializer.save()
        else:
            serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.save()

        return redirect('../../licsoftware/')
```

It's a nested (OneToOne) serializer with custom update and create methods.

From serializers.py:

```
class SoftwareSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Software
        fields = '__all__'

class LicensedSoftwareSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):

    software = SoftwareSerializer()
    available = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = LicensedSoftware
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('available',)

    def get_available(self, obj):
        return int(obj.numpurchased) - obj.software.assignees.count()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        software_data = validated_data.pop('software')
        software = instance.software
        for attr, value in software_data.items():
            if attr == 'assignees':
                instance.software.assignees.set(value)
            else:
                setattr(software, attr, value)
        software.save()
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, instance, validated_data):
        software_data = validated_data.pop('software')
        software = instance.software
        for attr, value in software_data.items():
            if attr == 'assignees':
                instance.software.assignees.set(value)
            else:
                setattr(software, attr, value)
        software.save()
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I have a template referencing the TemplateHTMLRenderer form and it works perfectly for updating when it can call a PK.  I can't, however, create a view or URL that will pull the form for a create/post.

Models:

```
class Software (models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False, verbose_name="Software Title")
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='software_assigned', blank=True, verbose_name="Installed Users:")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1} Version {2}".format(self.brand, self.title, str(self.version))


class LicensedSoftware(models.Model):

    software = models.OneToOneField(Software, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False, verbose_name="Contract/Purchase Vehicle")
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    licensekey = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    subscription = models.BooleanField()
    term = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    renewaldate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Renew By")
    supportincluded = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Support Included")
    numpurchased = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, verbose_name="Licenses Purchased")
```

Additional view that is not working and does not include the PK:

```
class LicensedSoftwareList(APIView):
    queryset = LicensedSoftware.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LicensedSoftwareSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'licsoftware-detail.html'

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        licsoftware = LicensedSoftware.objects.all()
        serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(licsoftware)
        return Response({'result': serializer.data})

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Licensed Software - {{ licensedsoftware.software.brand }} {{ licensedsoftware.software.title }} {{ licensedsoftware.software.version }}</h1>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/horizontal'%}
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('inventory/', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
    path('schema/', schema_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('inventory/mobile-detail/<int:pk>/', views.MobileDetail.as_view()),
    path('inventory/licsoftware-detail/<int:pk>/', views.LicensedSoftwareDetail.as_view()),
    path('inventory/licsoftware-detail/', views.LicensedSoftwareList.as_view()),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Documentation')),
    path('profiles/', views.ProfileList.as_view()),
    path('profile-detail/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileDetail.as_view()),
    path('inventory/licsoftware/', licensedsoftware_view, name='licensed_table'),
    path('inventory/mobile/', mobile_view, name='mobile_table'),
```

API Urls work.  Browseable API will allow create/post.
  path('inventory/licsoftware-detail//', views.LicensedSoftwareDetail.as_view()), works
        path('inventory/licsoftware-detail/', views.LicensedSoftwareList.as_view()), gives the error:

*Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `software` on serializer `LicensedSoftwareSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'software'.*

Comment: Why are you returning the serializer in your response? What specific error are you getting? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Whay does your urls.py our API routes look like?

Comment: I just want an auto generated input form to create new items in the above nested serialized models

Comment: Need more information. Show: models, template, and specific error or else we can't progress.

Comment: Edited to add the rest of the requested info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok,the way i understand your problem you want DRF to auto generate forms for Creating and Updating LicensedSoftware. So, i have tried to do that but in a little different way than you have i.e. i have used ModelViewSet in place of APIView and i have changed create function for both serializers.

Serializers.py

```html
class SoftwareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Software
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        assignees = validated_data.pop('assignees')

        software = Software.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for user in assignees:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
            software.assignees.add(user)
        return software


class LicensedSoftwareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    software = SoftwareSerializer()
    available = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = LicensedSoftware
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('available',)

    def get_available(self, obj):
        return int(obj.numpurchased) - obj.software.assignees.count()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        software_data = validated_data.pop('software')
        software = instance.software
        for attr, value in software_data.items():
            if attr == 'assignees':
                instance.software.assignees.set(value)
            else:
                setattr(software, attr, value)
        software.save()
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        software_data = validated_data.pop('software')
        assignee = software_data.pop("assignees")
        user_list = []
        for user in assignee:
            user_list.append(user.id)

        software_data.update({'assignees': user_list})

        software_serializer = SoftwareSerializer(data=software_data)

        software_serializer.is_valid()
        software = software_serializer.save()

        validated_data.update({"software": software})

        ls = LicensedSoftware.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return ls
```

views.py

```html
class LicensedSoftwareDetail(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = LicensedSoftware.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LicensedSoftwareSerializer
```

Feel free to mention if you want any changes here. And also as a suggestion, i would say create a separate end point for creating Software and then use PrimaryKeyRelated field or any other such field for the LicensedSoftwareSerializer because things get ugly when you use nested serializer. 
Peace

EDIT:

Okay, your view without pk is a little wrong for generating a create template.
This is how i made it work:

```html
class LicensedSoftwareCreate(APIView):
    queryset = LicensedSoftware.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LicensedSoftwareSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'licsoftware-detail.html'

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LicensedSoftwareSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem I have is these functions work fine in my current code, in the API views.  I need a frontend form using TemplateHTMLRenderer  that works FINE for my update when i can call a PK, but CANNOT find the view code to generate a blank form.

Comment: forgive me if i misunderstand but here,"I don't want to have to manually write forms to interact with the API for creating objects when the feature for auto-generated forms is there... but I'm completely at a loss."  aren't you asking that DRF auto create form for updation and creation

Comment: Yes.  It does.  It auto creates the form for updating with this code: 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms

Comment: Okay. What i have written generates forms for both creation and updation as well as listing all the objects in the database. Isn't that what you want.

Comment: They come up in the API.  My issue is rendering them in a frontend HTML template for a user to do the creation.  I cannot find documentation on displaying that form within my template.  So if your code does that I just need the tags to call that form in the template.

Comment: Those tags are created when that particular view is accessed, i don't see how you can call up those tags from a completely different view to render them in your own template. By the way if you are writing your own template why not just write your own form.

Comment: This application will have 10 or more serializers.  Manually creating individual frontend forms would not be efficient. DRF has a function to render the frontend forms.  The documentation shows how to do it for an UPDATE form.  I'm trying to find the way to render the CREATE form.

Comment: okay, i have updated my answer. Their was a slight problem in your additional view for creating form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183746/discussion-between-toni-marie-swats-and-dipen-bhatt).